# Cache all user On Behalf tokens in external redis cache

Tags: azure-ad-msal

We have a Azure APIM gateway where we are integrating 100s of different API for other teams. We have two clients mobile and web and with user token we will be calling Azure APIs and before calling 100s of API we generate on behalf of user token. We would like improve performance by caching all 100s of on behalf of user token per user in external redis cache . Would like to know is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In this [advanced token cache sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnet-advanced-token-cache), we cover a similar scenario of sharing the same external token cache with multiple applications, including background services that don't have user interactions but still can use the users token cached.